# WPF app for signing PDF with signature device

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I am writting application in WPF(C#) where you could view PDF and sign it. What I have now is I can view PDF in WPF form using acrobat component which is not Ok becuase I can't programatically save the file.

With iText I am able to put empty signature filed in PDF. But this field doesn't allow to sign it with pen. When you click on it offers you a certificate with which you could sign PDF. Is it possible directly sign PDF with pen from signature device?

Does anyone have solution how would achieve signing document with pen tool? Currently I am thinkig that would use some WPF component where you would put your signature, programatically save it like image and then put this image into PDF.

If this is right thinking I am wondering which WPF component would allow me to draw a signature?

If this is not right thinking I would like to know which PDF viewer to use which will allow me to view PDF and programatically save it. It will also allow me to click on signature field and sign it.

Please advice.

Regards,
Igor

Comment: Maybe have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570682/PDF-File-Writer-Csharp-Class-Library-Version

Comment: The signature field iText creates is for certificate based advanced or qualified digital signatures and is defined in the PDF specification. There is no PDF form field explicitly specified for drawn signatures. Some viewers may support proprietary extensions. Even though, you likely won't find support for such fields in general purpose PDF libraries.